# How to create a NumPy image array with the RGB value of each point using python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make something split an Image into two and merge the two images back.
I tried to use NumPy to minus a random value from each point on the image and store the value to make it a new image. Then I got a 'photo can not open this file because the formating is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted.' on the second image. So how can I create an image with these values?

```
import numpy
import random
from PIL import Image
a = Image.new('RGB', [1280, 720], (255, 255, 255))
a = numpy.array(a)
value = []
for x in a:
    for y in range(0, len(x)):
        temp = [random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(
            0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255)]
        b = numpy.array(temp)
        x[y] = x[y]-b
        value.append(temp)
a = Image.fromarray(a)
a.show()
#print(value)
#print(len(value))  # 1280*720=921600
c = numpy.array(value)
d = Image.fromarray(c)
d.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

When processing images with Python, you should try and use vectorised Numpy operations because they are much faster, and less prone to errors. If you start using Python `lists` and `for` loops, you have probably gone wrong already IMHO.

I am not certain, but I think you want to generate a random image and subtract it from an input image so you need both parts to recreate the whole, so I think you want code more like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open paddington and ensure he is 3-channel RGB rather than palette
im = Image.open('paddington.png').convert('RGB')

# Make Numpy array from him
na = np.array(im)

# Make another Numpy array (i.e. image) same size as Paddington and full of random numbers
rand = np.random.randint(0,256, na.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

# See how that looks
Image.fromarray(rand).show()

# Subtract random image from Paddington - this vectorised Numpy, fast and easy to get right
split = na - rand

# See how that looks
Image.fromarray(split).show()

# Recreate original by adding random image back to split - vectorised Numpy again
joined = split + rand

# See how that looks
Image.fromarray(joined).show()
```

[image]

[image]

---

If you prefer to persist with lists and `for` loops, there are a few issues in your code:

- you keep recycling `a`, so initially it is **PIL** `Image`, then it's a Numpy `array`, then a **PIL** `Image` so it is hard to refer back to anything you calculated earlier
- rather than `c = numpy.array(value)` which gives you an array of `np.int64`, you should use `c = numpy.array(value, dtype=np.uint8)` to get an unsigned 8-bit array, because **PIL** will not like 192-bits/pixel
- the shape of the Numpy array you create from the list will be wrong and need reshaping with `d = Image.fromarray(c.reshape(720,1280,3))`
- rather than calling `random.randrange()` three times for every pixel and converting the result to a Numpy array, you could call `np.random.randint(0,256,(3),dtype=np.uint8)` to get all three values as a Numpy array in one call
- you are probably going to have problems with overflows and underflows since you lose the underlying type of values in lists

Answer (score 0):

```
b = a.copy()
for position, color_value in numpy.ndenumerate(a):
    b[position] = abs(color_value - random.randrange(0, 255))

d = Image.fromarray(b)
d.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30221112)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I tried to create a new white Image of the same size and loop through it to add values.

```
import numpy
import random
from PIL import Image
a = Image.open('test.jpg')
a = numpy.array(a)
value = []
for x in a:
    for y in range(0, len(x)):
        temp = [random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255)]
        b = numpy.array(temp)
        x[y] = x[y]-b
        value.append(temp)
a = Image.fromarray(a)
b=Image.new('RGB',a.size,(255,255,255))
b=numpy.array(b)
counter=0
for x in b:
    for y in range(0,len(x)):
        x[y]=tuple(value[counter])
        counter+=1
b=Image.fromarray(b)
a=numpy.array(a)
b=numpy.array(b)
a=numpy.add(a,b)
a=Image.fromarray(a)
a.show()
```